# Highcharts conditional DrillDown not hiding DrillUp Button

Tags: highcharts, drilldown

I'm trying to avoid the chart's drilldown when the user clicks the x-Axis label, but, unless I'm doing something wrong, the DrillUpButton doesn't dissapear completly when I cancel the event:

[image]

```
    chart: {
                type: "column",
                events: {
                    drilldown: function (e) 
                    {  
                    if (e.category != null)
                            return false;
                    }
                }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ar3k9wda/3/

Is this a bug??? Or what else do I need to do???

Answer (score 3):

You want to disable data label click. check this [post](https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/having-trouble-removing-x-axis-functionality-t34006/) it will be help full

```js
Highcharts.Tick.prototype.drillable = function () {};
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
                    type: "column",
                    /*events: {
                        drilldown: function (e) 
                        {  
                        if (e.category != null)
                                return false;
                        }
                    }*/
            }, 
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },   
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33,
            drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 24.03,
            drilldown: 'Chrome'
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.38,
            drilldown: 'Firefox'
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.77,
            drilldown: 'Safari'
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 0.91,
            drilldown: 'Opera'
        }, {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            y: 0.2,
            drilldown: null
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {       
        series: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            data: [
                [
                    'v11.0',
                    24.13
                ],
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    17.2
                ],
                [
                    'v9.0',
                    8.11
                ],
                [
                    'v10.0',
                    5.33
                ],
                [
                    'v6.0',
                    1.06
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.5
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            id: 'Chrome',
            data: [
                [
                    'v40.0',
                    5
                ],
                [
                    'v41.0',
                    4.32
                ],
                [
                    'v42.0',
                    3.68
                ],
                [
                    'v39.0',
                    2.96
                ],
                [
                    'v36.0',
                    2.53
                ],
                [
                    'v43.0',
                    1.45
                ],
                [
                    'v31.0',
                    1.24
                ],
                [
                    'v35.0',
                    0.85
                ],
                [
                    'v38.0',
                    0.6
                ],
                [
                    'v32.0',
                    0.55
                ],
                [
                    'v37.0',
                    0.38
                ],
                [
                    'v33.0',
                    0.19
                ],
                [
                    'v34.0',
                    0.14
                ],
                [
                    'v30.0',
                    0.14
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            id: 'Firefox',
            data: [
                [
                    'v35',
                    2.76
                ],
                [
                    'v36',
                    2.32
                ],
                [
                    'v37',
                    2.31
                ],
                [
                    'v34',
                    1.27
                ],
                [
                    'v38',
                    1.02
                ],
                [
                    'v31',
                    0.33
                ],
                [
                    'v33',
                    0.22
                ],
                [
                    'v32',
                    0.15
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            id: 'Safari',
            data: [
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    2.56
                ],
                [
                    'v7.1',
                    0.77
                ],
                [
                    'v5.1',
                    0.42
                ],
                [
                    'v5.0',
                    0.3
                ],
                [
                    'v6.1',
                    0.29
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.26
                ],
                [
                    'v6.2',
                    0.17
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            id: 'Opera',
            data: [
                [
                    'v12.x',
                    0.34
                ],
                [
                    'v28',
                    0.24
                ],
                [
                    'v27',
                    0.17
                ],
                [
                    'v29',
                    0.16
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: But this code disable the data label click for all my charts. What about if I want to disable it just for a specific one?

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47330088/3898339) . Apply to this code